# Make Just One Block Collapsible?

Tags: blocks, javascript

Hi ive been searching about for an answer for this for over an hour now. I know there is the collapible block module but i was hoping to use drupals inbuilt collapisble code just on the block in question. I dont seem to be able to do it.

The block is a Views block if that makes any differance and i am using D6.

Thanks

Comment: I found an article here. http://blog.lightrains.com/drupal/make-collapsible-div-drupal-7/ . It says its for D7 but giv a try.

Comment: Soz Nik i was wanting yto avoid ctools at all costs on my site. Ran into probs with it before but thanks. The BBC have exactlly what i am after below their videos on the iplayer http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer in the More Program Information bit. tx